# login con spring boot usando jdbc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Como puedo autenticarme en spring boot usando jdbc

```
auth
        .jdbcAuthentication()
        .dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(new Md5PasswordEncoder())    
        .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password,enabled from user where username=?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT role from user_role inner join user on user.id_user_rol = user_role.id where user.username=?");
```

mi base de datos

```
CREATE DATABASE db_srp;

USE db_srp;

CREATE TABLE user_role(
id int auto_increment,
role varchar(15),
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE user(
id int auto_increment,
username varchar(50),
password varchar(100),
enabled boolean,
id_user_rol int,
PRIMARY KEY(id),
FOREIGN KEY(id_user_rol) REFERENCES user_role(id)
);
```

Comment: Te recomiendo utilizar un user detail service [https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-jdbc-authentication](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-jdbc-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Solo necesitas agregar las credenciales para conectarte en el archivo de propiedades de tu proyecto /resources/application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

Tambien es importante que en tu pom este la dependencia del driver de BD que te quieres conectar. Con esto Spring Boot detecta la conexion que quieres hacer y configura lo necesario.

Saludos